# javascript shift() weird recursive with return

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, while-loop, shift

Does anybody see below javascript recursive with shift() return? Even three times shift() array still run 'while loop'

```
function combine(nums) {
    while (nums.length) {
        let r = nums.shift();
        console.log(r, ':',  nums);
        combine(nums.slice(0));
  }
}

combine([1,2,3])
---------------  return -----------
    1 : [ 2, 3 ]
    2 : [ 3 ]
    3 : []
    3 : []
    2 : [ 3 ]
    3 : []
    3 : []
------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's correct as marked duplicate by Andy. I forget to add return combine(nums.slice(0)); Thank you Andy

Comment: A `return` will avoid `while` to continue the next iteration.

Comment: I agree Akshay's reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The slice() method returns a **shallow copy** of a portion of an array into a new array object

By calling `combine(nums.slice(0))` you are not performing next function call on same the `nums` array, cause `slice` will return new array.

Use:

```js
function combine(nums) {
    while (nums.length) {
        let r = nums.shift();
        console.log(r, ':',  nums);
        combine(nums);
  }
}

combine([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works as expected. I altered it slightly to maybe show you more clearly why it behaves this way:

Also, what's your question?

```
function combine(nums, depth) {
  console.log(`Starting depth ${depth} with [${nums}]`);
    while (nums.length) {
      let r = nums.shift();
      let newArr = nums.slice(0);
      console.log(`Removed "${r}". Firing with [${newArr}]`);
      combine(nums.slice(0), depth+1);
      console.log(`Returned to depth ${depth}`);
  }
  console.log(`While end at depth ${depth}`);
}

combine([1,2,3], 0)
```

Comment: I am very impressed by kaczmen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldn't "combine" **recursion** and **while loop**. Even more, I believe recursion is a bad practice.

```js
function combine(nums) {
    while (nums.length) {
        let r = nums.shift();
        console.log(r, ':',  nums);
        //combine(nums.slice(0)); <- this line is a problem
  }
}

combine([1,2,3])
---------------  return -----------
    1 : [ 2, 3 ]
    2 : [ 3 ]
    3 : []
------------------------------------
```